# Magento 2 : After login need to redirect on same page instead of customer Dashboard

Tags: magento2, customer, login, redirect-url

After login redirect user on previous page from front-end.

I am using the login pop-up and all default functionality. Also the Admin configuration **Redirect Customer to Account** is set as No. But it redirect me on `Customer Dashboard`.

Comment: Found this extension, easy and perfect
https://magecomp.com/magento-2-custom-redirect.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set config setting in Admin:

> STORES > Configuration > CUSTOMERS > Customer Configuration > Login Options > Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in > No.

**Also we have to enable Guest checkout**.

Comment: Not working, still have the referer link....

Comment: No need to enable Guest Checkout. Just flush the cache properly and maybe browser cache as well.

Comment: lol, why you have to enable guest checkout, it has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 9):

We can config in Admin: **STORES > Configuration > CUSTOMERS > Customer Configuration > Login Options > Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in > No**.

[image]

When enabled this config, the login url will have a referer param to [base64 encode url](https://www.base64decode.org/), like: `http://{website_url}/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9tYWdlMjE=/`

Technically, we should take a look:

**vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php**

```
 public function execute()
 {
        ......
        return $this->accountRedirect->getRedirect();
 }
```

**vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Account/Redirect.php**

```
/**
 * Retrieve redirect
 *
 * @return ResultRedirect|ResultForward
 */
public function getRedirect()
{
     ......
}
```

**UPDATE:** Please delete your local storage, this feature will work well. Please read more [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134808/magento-2-redirect-customer-to-custom-page-after-login/134846#134846).

**Magento Version:**

*-Magento version 2.1.0*

Comment: I already set this to NO. But its not working for me.

Comment: You choose correct store view or any customized?

Comment: I already checked all these setting and all are proper. If you have any idea which methods is responsible for this setting for redirect so that I can check there for the value of this setting ?

Comment: I updated some useful methods. You should take a look.

Comment: When I enable the guest checkout its working fine. Is it possible to set this only for customer ?