# Magento 2 - Redirect customer to custom page after login

Tags: magento2, customer, login

Which class I should override in order to redirect a customer to a specific page after login?

I have tried to set `Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in` in the store configuration but it is not working.

Comment: You enable or disable Guest Checkout?

Comment: I have disabled guest checkout.

Comment: How about your current issue?

Comment: The code you provided is a bit different from my magento. Maybe it from different versions. And I don't understand why it is related to cookie. I finally resolved it by overriding the LoginPost class. I posted my answer below. Thanks!

Comment: My Magento version is 2.1.0 and you?

Comment: My magento version is v2.0.8

Comment: How you fixed your problem? Can you explain more?

Comment: I posted my answer. I resolved it by overriding the LoginPost class. In the class, I use the redirectResultFactory to set the redirect path.

Comment: Yeah! You're right! I have just checked the older version! Magento 2.1.0 code lines differ from v2.0.8. I also need to update the version on my answer.

Comment: Did you check out this extension ? https://magecomp.com/magento-2-custom-redirect.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved it by overriding the LoginPost class

**etc/di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Account\LoginPost" />
```

**Vendor/Module/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\EmailNotConfirmedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class LoginPost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost {

    public function execute() {
        if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('home');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                try {
                    $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($login['username'], $login['password']);
                    $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
                    $this->session->regenerateId();
                } catch (EmailNotConfirmedException $e) {
                    $value = $this->customerUrl->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                    $message = __(
                            'This account is not confirmed.' .
                            ' <a href="%1">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
                    $message = __('Invalid login or password.');
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->messageManager->addError(__('Invalid login or password.'));
                }
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('A login and a password are required.'));
            }
        }

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('home');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think using a plugin with the `afterExecute()` would be a cleaner option

Comment: This not a good approach and will only cause problems in the future. Plugin is the way to go.

Comment: can we redirect from account dashboard to sales order history page by default?

Comment: yeah,plugin is right option but using this if the customer tries to login and fails, then you're still going to hit the home page.

Comment: Above preference code is not working.......

Answer (score 41):

A plugin is a better solution in this case because your extended class might need to be updated when Magento 2 updates.

Here is a solution using a after-plugin on LoginPost->execute() as suggested by Xenocide8998.

`/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
    <plugin name="vendor_module_loginpostplugin" type="\Vendor\Module\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
  </type>
</config>
```

`/Vendor/Module/Plugin/LoginPostPlugin.php`:

```
<?php

/**
 *
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

/**
 *
 */
class LoginPostPlugin
{

    /**
     * Change redirect after login to home instead of dashboard.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result
     */
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
        $result)
    {
        $result->setPath('/'); // Change this to what you want
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's work well. One thing is when you need to $result->setPath('/'); to your custom path don't use "/" before URL,

for example. $result->setPath('customer/dashboard/');

Comment: Good approach using plugin

Comment: Perfect Work thank you

Comment: Your only issue with this is if the customer tries to login and fails, then you're still going to hit the home page. There isn't any way to catch failed logins.

Comment: how can I pass current page url to this plugin?

Comment: If customer tries to login and fails,in this case using above code you'll also redirect to homepage...which is bad experience for the user...to get rid off this...you can also check if customer is logged-in or not in the above solution.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution that i found

> If the custom URL is **sales/order/history**

**Vendor/Extension/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
        <plugin name="redirect_custom_url" type="VendorName\Extension\Plugin\RedirectCustomUrl" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Extension/Plugin/RedirectCustomUrl.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin;
class RedirectCustomUrl
{
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
        $result)
    {
        $customUrl = 'sales/order/history';
        $result->setPath($customUrl);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

*Vote this answer up if it helps.*

Comment: Yes, It worked!

Answer (score 0):

**That the current local storage caused our issue.**
If we enable or disable `Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in` and Guest Checkout in Configuration, this feature will work well. However, we need to clear your local storage.

We can check the local storage `localStorage.getItem('mage-cache-storage')`.

Take a look:

*vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js*

```
var cart = customerData.get('cart'),
customer = customerData.get('customer');
if (!customer().firstname && cart().isGuestCheckoutAllowed === false) {
    // set URL for redirect on successful login/registration. It's postprocessed on backend.
    $.cookie('login_redirect', this.options.url.checkout);
    if (this.options.url.isRedirectRequired) {
        location.href = this.options.url.loginUrl;
    } else {
        authenticationPopup.showModal();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Magento will set the cookie `$.cookie('login_redirect', this.options.url.checkout)` based on `customerData` from local storage.

From the controller `vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php`. It will check the redirect URL from the cookie.

```
$redirectUrl = $this->accountRedirect->getRedirectCookie();
if (!$this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard') && $redirectUrl) {
    ......
    return $resultRedirect;
}
```

**Magento version:**

*-Magento version 2.1.0*

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by passing **referer** in custom module controller.

**Step1**
`

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Approve extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    /** 
    * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page 
    */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /** 
    * $param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context */

    /**
    * @param CustomerSession
    */

    protected $_customerSession;

    protected $_urlInterface;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        Session $customerSession,
        UrlInterface $urlInterface
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_customerSession  = $customerSession;
        $this->_urlInterface     = $urlInterface;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }

    public function execute(){
        $url  = $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]); 
// here pass custom url or you can either use current url on which you are currently and want to come back after logged in.

        $loginUrl = $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('customer/account/login', array('referer' => base64_encode($url)));
        if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
            return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        }
        $this->_redirect($loginUrl);
    }
}`
```

**Step2**

Go to Admin : Store > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Login Options > Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in > No

Answer (score 0):

I've created a module that allows me to specify the `redirectUrl` via querystring when redirecting customers to `/customer/account/login`.

For example /customer/account/login?redirectUrl=https://someurl.com or ?redirectUrl=some/path.

I did this by creating 2 plugins:

##### 1. Plugin for `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Login`

Just to capture the parameter `redirectUrl` and save it to the customer session.

```php
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

class CustomerLoginPlugin
{
    private Session $session;
    private Http $httpRequest;

    public function __construct(Session $session, Http $httpRequest)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->httpRequest = $httpRequest;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Login $subject
     * @param                                            $result
     */
    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Login $subject, $result)
    {
        if ($redirectUrl = $this->httpRequest->getParam('redirectUrl', false)) {
            $this->session->setRedirectUrl($redirectUrl);
        }
        
        return $result;
    }
}
```

##### 2. Plugin for `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost`

This will change the response in case the response is a redirect. So, if we have no errors in the loginPost response, I change the redirect url.

```php
use Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class CustomerLoginPostPlugin
{
    private Session $session;

    public function __construct(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject
     * @param                                                $result
     */
    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject, $result)
    {
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect && $this->session->getRedirectUrl()) {
            $result->setPath($this->session->getRedirectUrl());
        }
        
        return $result;
    }
}
```

##### Example of use

```php
if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $resultRedirect = $this->redirectFactory->create();
    $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account/login', ['redirectUrl'=>'some/pathOrUrl']);
    return $resultRedirect;
}
```

Note that if you want to always redirect to some specific url, you can ignore the first Plugin, and just replace the `setPath` parameter to whatever you want (answering the original question).