# Login Page in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2.1.0, and i want  to create custom login page and registration page with custom group.

So I am trying  to override the customer login controller, and Phtml files.

But I don't understand what all changes needed their to assign the other group and [MINI TUTORIAL: CREATE YOUR OWN LOGIN PAGE USING MAGENTO’S ACCOUNTCONTROLLER](https://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/tutorial-create-your-own-login-page-using-magentos-accountcontroller/) which all file need to override.

and will it work like as customer login?

I found this tutorial , But it is for magento 1.x and not for other group

Comment: Please check below URL, 
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134808/magento-2-redirect-customer-to-custom-page-after-login