# How can i redirect to homepage after login

Tags: magento2, redirect

I have used following code for redirect to homepage. But the page not redirecting after login.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\EmailNotConfirmedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class LoginPost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost {

    public function execute() {
        if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('home');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                try {
                    $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($login['username'], $login['password']);
                    $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
                    $this->session->regenerateId();
                } catch (EmailNotConfirmedException $e) {
                    $value = $this->customerUrl->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                    $message = __(
                            'This account is not confirmed.' .
                            ' <a href="%1">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
                    $message = __('Invalid login or password.');
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->messageManager->addError(__('Invalid login or password.'));
                }
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('A login and a password are required.'));
            }
        }

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('home'); // set this path to what you want your customer to go
        return $resultRedirect;
    }

}
```

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/193176/38476

Comment: @Nits, is correct why override full controller, we can do that by plugin.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code for fast :

```
$this->_redirect('home');
```

See my screen below :
[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have set path at home

But you need to set like below:

add storemanager in your construct:

> \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storemanager
>   $this->_storemanager=$storemanager

$redirectUrl= $this->_storemanager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();

> $resultRedirect->setPath($redirectUrl);

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code for your controller:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\EmailNotConfirmedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class LoginPost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost {

    public function execute() {
        if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                try {
                    $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($login['username'], $login['password']);
                    $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
                    $this->session->regenerateId();
                } catch (EmailNotConfirmedException $e) {
                    $value = $this->customerUrl->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                    $message = __(
                            'This account is not confirmed.' .
                            ' <a href="%1">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
                    $message = __('Invalid login or password.');
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->messageManager->addError(__('Invalid login or password.'));
                }
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('A login and a password are required.'));
            }
        }

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath(''); // set this path to what you want your customer to go
        return $resultRedirect;
    }

}
```

Above I have changed the 'home' to '' for both section which means it will redirect to homepage. As if you change the identifier of CMS home page then your code will not work as you have mentioned it home hardcoded but above code will redirect you to the homepage everytime.

Also you need use the following code in your di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Account\LoginPost" />
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be [RedirectAfterLogin](https://github.com/csvikram44/RedirectAfterLogin) Magento 2 module will help you.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storemanager, 
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect)
{
    $this->_storemanager=$storemanager;
    $this->_resultRedirect=$resultRedirect;
}

public function afterExecute(
    \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject, $result)
{
    $redirectUrl= $this->_storemanager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    $this->_resultRedirect->setPath($redirectUrl);
    return $this->_resultRedirect;
}
```