# Magento 2: Set order history page as default after login

Tags: magento2, order-history, account-dashboard

I am trying to set the order history page as the default page when the customer is logged in.

When the customer login is successful, it redirects to **customer/account/**

Instead of this can we direct to **sales/order/history/**

So when the customer login happens, he can see order history page instead of the dashboard page.

Is something like that can be achieved? Can anyone help me on this issue, please?

Thanks

Comment: check this, it will help you . https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134808/magento-2-redirect-customer-to-custom-page-after-login

Comment: @ManashviBirla, this will work only if we do login, I am looking for even if they open dashboard page, it should redirect to history page..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

override account controller as like below.

**Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">       
   <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Account\ExtendIndex" /> 
</config>
```

Then, **Vendor\Module\Controller\Account\ExtendIndex.php**

```
<?php
 namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Account;
 class ExtendIndex extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index
 {
   public function execute()
  {
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/order/history');
    return $resultRedirect;
  }
}
```

**I hope this will help you!!**

Comment: Thank you it worked !! @jafar

Comment: I have one question how user access  to dashboard?

Comment: @Addify,its not required in my requirement!

Answer (score 4):

Override the `LoginPost` controller and set the redirect to `history` controller in the plugin

> Filepath: Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
    <plugin name="vendor_module_loginpostplugin" type="\Vendor\Module\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
  </type>
</config>
```

> Filepath: Vendor/Module/Plugin/LoginPostPlugin.php:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class LoginPostPlugin
{

    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
        $result)
    {
        $result->setPath('sales/order/history'); 
        return $result;
    }

}
```

**Note:Code tested**

Answer (score 3):

You can change My Account link by plugin

Add below code to **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Url">
    <plugin name="custom_links" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Url" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Url.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Url
{
    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;


    /**
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

    public function afterGetAccountUrl(\Magento\Customer\Model\Url $subject, $result)
    {
        return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('sales/order/history');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> 1. events.xml file in app\code\Vendore\Module\etc\frontend folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="customer_login_success_after_order" instance="Vendore\Module\Observer\CustomerLogin" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> 2. Create CustomerLogin.php file in app\code\Vendore\Module\Observer folder

```
<?php

namespace Builderschoice\CustomModule\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Builderschoice\Company\Model\CompanyFactory;


class CustomerLogin implements ObserverInterface
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory
 */
protected $responseFactory;

protected $webkulData;

protected $_companyBlock;

protected $_companyFactory;

protected $_storeManagerInterface;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 * @param \Zend\Validator\Uri $uri
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    \Webkul\Marketplace\Helper\Data $webkulData,
    \Builderschoice\Company\Block\Index\Index $companyBlock,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface,
    CompanyFactory $companyFactory
) {
    $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    $this->webkulData = $webkulData;
    $this->_companyBlock = $companyBlock;
    $this->_storeManagerInterface = $storeManagerInterface;
    $this->_companyFactory = $companyFactory;
}
/**
 * Handler for 'customer_login' event.
 *
 * @param Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $customer = $event->getCustomer();

    $storeManager = $this->_storeManagerInterface->create();
    $baseurl=$storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    $url = $baseurl.'sales/order/history';

    $resultRedirect = $this->responseFactory->create();

    $resultRedirect->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse('200');

    exit();
}
}
```