# Magento 2 When a user logs in, can we redirect to homepage?

Tags: magento2.2, redirect, user-account

I would like to have the user redirected to homepage instead of dashboard as soon as he logs in.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134808/magento-2-redirect-customer-to-custom-page-after-login

Answer (score 0):

Use plugin concept and redirect to magento2 home page after login user successfully.

/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
    <plugin name="vendor_module_loginpostplugin" type="\Vendor\Module\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
  </type>
</config>
```

/Vendor/Module/Plugin/LoginPostPlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
class LoginPostPlugin
{

    /**
     * Change redirect after login to home instead of dashboard.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result
     */
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
        $result)
    {
        $result->setPath('/'); // Change this to what you want
        return $result;
    }

}
```