# Customers being redirected to checkout after login

Tags: login, redirect, magento2.4

Title says it all. After a customer logs in, it redirects them to checkout. What could be causing that?

I have a plugin that does login for pricing, but this happens even when I disable it. The option to redirect to cart after adding an item to cart is set to no.

Comment: maybe cookie issue? did you try different browsers, incognito mode?

Comment: maybe it is set to yes on store level. have you check it ?

Comment: Please refer this, it may help
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134808/magento-2-redirect-customer-to-custom-page-after-login

Comment: you need to login after redirect to checkout right?

Comment: Incogneto and clearing cookies doesn't work. It's not set differently on the store level. I need to go back to the page that the customer was on before he tried to log in