# Magento 2: Modify authentication-popup.html form action

Tags: magento2, javascript, customer, overrides

Authentication popup is the login popup that will appear if customer who are not logged in press **Proceed to Checkout** button in cart page.

For default, when customer sign in using authentication popup they will be redirected to the previous page (cart page).

I want to modify **the redirect url after customer sign in from authentication pop up**, they'll redirected to custom page. I have trying to locate the form action in `Magento_Customer/view/frontend/web/js/view/authentication-popup.js` but i can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path should be : `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/web/js/view/authentication-popup.js`

For the simple way, we can set the redirect url in our custom js - `authentication-popup.js`:

```
        /** Provide login action */
        login: function (loginForm) {

          ...... 
                this.isLoading(true);
                loginAction(loginData, null, false); // We can set the redirect here
          ......
        }
```

Take the look the `loginAction` method - `Magento_Customer/js/action/login`.

```
                   if (redirectUrl) {
                        window.location.href = redirectUrl;
                    } else if (response.redirectUrl) {
                        window.location.href = response.redirectUrl;
                    } else {
                        location.reload();
                    }
```

As we can see, if we set the redirect url by default, Magento site will use it for redirecting.

For the redirect Url, we can read more here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/131227/33057

Comment: yes, i have created authentication-popup.js in that directory. now i want to change the redirect url after customer login.

Comment: Which the redirect url you want after customer login?

Comment: to checkout page.

Comment: You should read more here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/131227/33057

Comment: I have set **Redirects to Account Dashboard** to Yes. Then i'm trying login using authentication pop up, it still redirect to cart, not to customer dashboard. I think log in using authentication popup has different redirect url than usual way.

Comment: @SeventhSt see my updated answer with js way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53416/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-seventh-st).

Comment: @SeventhSt after changing setting in admin config, we may need to clear **Local Storage** in your Browser.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I don't think modifying code library is good Idea... We should use mixin to achieve this

Comment: Yes, @BEJGAMSHIVAPRASAD I will update my code if having free time. thanks. Or, you can edit my answer with your update info.